# What's the square root of i to the power of 4?

Tags: irrational-numbers, paradoxes

**This is not a homework question**

$\sqrt{i^4} = \sqrt{1} = 1$

$\sqrt{i^4}=i^{\frac{4}{2}}\ =\ i^2=-1$

So what did I do wrong?

Comment: Later on, if you ever decide to learn complex analysis, you will learn about branches of multi-valued functions and realize that these two solutions correspond to the two branches of $\sqrt{z}$!

Answer (score 2):

Another fun paradox: $-1 = (-1)^1 = (-1)^{2/2} = ((-1)^2)^{1/2} = 1^{1/2} = 1$.

More seriously, the property $x^{a b} = (x^a)^b$ only applies for positive real $x$.

Comment: The Jonathans agree!

Answer (score 1):

The property :

$$\sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}$$

only applies for $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not exactly sure what does the symbol means. Can you tell me the name of the symbol so I can google it?

Comment: What symbol? He's saying this only works for real $x$.

Comment: @JasonLI Hi. What symbol are you referring too ?

Comment: I was asking about the real number symbol. But then why this property only applys to real number?

Comment: @JasonLI Because from your own example, as you saw, it does not apply to imaginary numbers (or complex numbers). This is because such expressions become undefined in the way the real plane and such properties are built.

Answer (score 0):

Every nonzero complex number has two square roots whose arguments are 180 degrees apart in the complex plane. You have not done anything wrong and have shown that the number $i^{4}=1$ has two square roots namely $\pm1$.

Answer (score 0):

In your second equation you've used the property $$(x^a)^b = x^{ab}.$$ Generally you should only use this when $x$ is guaranteed to be a positive real number. You can put different conditions on $x$ (e.g. positive), or $a$ and $b$ (e.g. whole numbers) and still have it work out correctly, but you're really asking for trouble.